# call mail function in json response in laravel

Tags: php, jquery, json, laravel, email

I want to call mail function in jquery page in laravel 5.3.I have the mail router names as 'welcome-mail'

```
Route::get('welcome-mail','travelerHome@welcomeMail');

Controller 
 public function welcomeMail()
{
    $to_email = 'sample@domain.com';
    Mail::to($to_email)->send(new Reminder);
    //return "E-mail has been sent Successfully";  
}

mail/Remainder.php
public function build()
{
    return $this->from('sample@toDomain.com')
                ->view('email.welcome');
}

view/email/welcome.blade.php
<html>
<body>
  <h3>Hi,</h3> 
   <p>Test mail Travel approval</p>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to call this function in json response or in json url

```
if(approve_id=='Y'){
    var status = 'approved';
    $.ajax({
  url: 'request-status',
  type: 'GET',
  data: {'id':user_id,'status':status,'comment':comment}, 
  dataType: 'JSON',
  success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
    //alert(data);
    url: 'welcome-mail'   //want to call like this
    $(".table-responsive").load(location.href + " .table-responsive");
  },
  error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
 // alert('errror');

  },
});
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please handle your welcome-mail in controller request-status in place of ajax response.

Or

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "/request-status",
  data: {'id':user_id,'status':status,'comment':comment}, 
  success: function (data) { SuccessCall(data); },
  error: function (xhr, status, error) { alert(error); }
         });


function SuccessCall(data){
 $.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 url: "welcome-mail",
 success: function (data) { //Success message },
 error: function (xhr, status, error) { alert(error); }
 });
 }
```

Comment: in my controller I tried as //Route::get('welcome-mail','travelerHome@welcomeMail');